# Select remove duplicate Account number and include other fields

Tags: sql, sql-server, duplicates

I am trying to remove duplicate accountno's from my table.

SELECT     ACCOUNTNO, DateTime, RESULTCODE, REF
FROM         dbo.Most_Recent_Result

I have tried DISTINCT but the REF is different on some of the rows.

How do I remove duplicate accountno's?  I just want to remove the second matching accountno record.

Comment: It would be helpful to know what database you're using.  -- MySQL?  PostgreSQL?  SQL Server?  etc...

Comment: I am using SQL Server 2014

Comment: It would also be helpful to see a sample of your data table. As I understand it, you have multiple ACCOUNTNO entries with various DateTimes, and you want to only keep the one with the most recent DateTime, is that correct?

Comment: Yes, I also only want to select one Accoutno.  In some cases there are two rows with the same date and the same Accountno.  I only want to end up with one row in this situation

Comment: 123abc   01012017  COD  Description1

Comment: 123abc 01012017 COD Description2

Comment: I only need to keep one of these

Comment: Is this a case where there are multiple sets of duplicate ACCOUNTNOs and you want to end up with only one of each or is it that there is a specific ACCOUNTNO (or just a few) that need to be dealt with?  That is, do you need a statement that will handle all such cases generically or could it be `WHERE ACCOUNTNO = '123abc'`?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT ACCOUNTNO, DateTime, RESULTCODE, REF
FROM dbo.datetime as o
LEFT JOIN (SELECT ACCOUNTNO, MAX(datetime) AS max_datetime
        FROM dbo.datetime GROUP BY ACCOUNTNO) i ON o.ACCOUNTNO = i.ACCOUNTNO
WHERE o.DateTime = i.max_datetime
```

This assumes that for each ACCOUNTNO duplicate entry, none exist that have the same DateTime, otherwise you will still get duplicates.

**EDIT:** Because your data has multiple ACCOUNTNOs with the same date, at this point you can add in a DISTINCT keyword. That will remove the duplicates of the maximum date for each ACCOUNTNO

**EDIT 2:** If you do not care about which RESULTCODE and REF fields will display, you can use an aggregate function to get only one:

```
SELECT DISTINCT o.ACCOUNTNO, o.DateTime, MAX(o.RESULTCODE), MAX(o.REF)
FROM dbo.datetime as o
LEFT JOIN (SELECT ACCOUNTNO, MAX(datetime) AS max_datetime
    FROM dbo.datetime GROUP BY ACCOUNTNO) i ON o.ACCOUNTNO = i.ACCOUNTNO
WHERE o.DateTime = i.max_datetime
GROUP BY o.ACCOUNTNO, o.DateTime
ORDER BY ACCOUNTNO
```

Comment: There are records that have the same accountno and date, I am trying to get rid of the duplicate, I only want one record for each Accountno

Comment: See edit. Unless your RESULTCODE and REF fields also have different values for that maximum date. If so, I hope you can at least see where I'm going with this to get to your answer. If you really care about a different value in REF or RESULTCODE, then you don't really want to remove those duplicate records.

Comment: I don't care about the value in the REF or RESULTCODE for this table,  In most situations they would be the same.  I just need those fields for formulas in a report.

Comment: The most recent code still produced duplicate Acountno's

Comment: Could I create a View of this View that would be easier to remove the duplicate Accountno's?

Comment: @SRC It's producing duplicate accountnos because you have different values for REF and RESULTCODE. Here's the question: do you even want those values at all? Because if you don't, then just don't select them. If you don't care what one you get, then use a simple aggregate function as I show in my second edit.

Answer (score 0):

Pls try this:

```
  select   accountno, datetime, resultcode, ref 
  from ( 
  select dense_rank() over (partition by accountno order by datetime desc, ref ) as rn
  ,accountno, datetime, resultcode, ref 
  from dto.datetime
  )
where rn = 1
order by 1,2
```

Here is my [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dense-rank-transact-sql).

Comment: SQL text cannot be represented in the grid pane and diagram pane.

Comment: This error is due to the view designer itself.  Check out this link: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e3036b3d-0f61-4aec-a879-f6602e86515b/sql-server-2008-management-studios-why-do-i-get-sql-text-cannot-be-represented-in-the-grid-pane?forum=sqltools